# Multiplying large numbers as strings - everything fine unless there is a 9 in the numbers

Tags: c++, string, multiplication, largenumber

I had to create a class in C++ - BigInteger - that works with very large numbers that are written in the form of strings. As part of the assignment, I also had to predefine multiplication, and here's what I did:

```
BigInteger& BigInteger::operator*(const BigInteger& rhs)
{
    string tmp(num.length() + rhs.num.length(), '0');
    //a string in which I'll be temporarily storing the result
    char carry = '0';
    int d = 0;
    //I'll use this to move with one index to the left in the result 
    for (int i = num.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    //start with the multiplying from the end of the first number
    {
        carry = '0';
        for (int j = rhs.num.length() - 1, z = tmp.length() - 1 - d; j >= 0; --j, --z)
        //start with the multiplying from the end of the second number and begin filling the result string (again from the end)
        {
            tmp[z] = ((tmp[z] - '0') + (num[i] - '0') * (rhs.num[j] - '0') + (carry - '0')) + '0';
            //basically add to the current number in the result the multiplication of the respective digits in the two original numbers, plus the carry from the previous mutiplication
            carry = ((tmp[z] - '0') / 10) + '0';
            tmp[z] = ((tmp[z] - '0') % 10) + '0';
            if (j == 0 && carry != '0')
            {
                tmp[z - 1] = carry;
            }
        }
        ++d;
    }
    if (carry != '0')
    {
        tmp[0] = carry;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp.erase(0, 1);
    }
    num = tmp;
    return *this;
}
```

Everything works fine even with large numbers like 123456788*887654321, but once I try multiplying numbers containing a 9 in them (including smaller ones like 6789*9876), not only are the middle digits off, but there are differences between 6789*9876 and 9876*6789, including signs like "+" and apostrophe appearing roughly in the center in the latter case.

Has anyone here encountered such a problem or has any idea what might be causing it?

EDIT:
Here's the predefined << operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BigInteger& rhs)
{
    out << rhs.num;
    return out;
}
```

and my "main":

```
#include "BigInteger.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    BigInteger num3("123456788");
    BigInteger num4("887654321");
    cout << num3 * num4 << endl;
    //cout << num4 * num3 << endl;
}
```

and my class:

```
#ifndef H_BIGINTEGER
#define H_BIGINTEGER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//I know I shouldn't have defined a namespace in the headers file, but left it for brevity's sake

class BigInteger
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const BigInteger&);

public:
    BigInteger();
    BigInteger(string);
    ~BigInteger();
    BigInteger(const BigInteger&);
    BigInteger& operator=(const BigInteger&);

    BigInteger& operator+(BigInteger&);
    BigInteger& operator-(BigInteger&);
    BigInteger& operator*(const BigInteger&);

private:
    string num;
};
```

the constructor I'm using is just:

```
BigInteger::BigInteger(string num)
    :num(num)
{}
```

Comment: What is `BigInteger`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: the complexity of the code is beyond what my brain can process :P. Imho its easier to write a method that adds only at a certain position and call that recursively

Comment: Thanks for adding the `main()`.  You're still missing a definition of `BigInteger` before we're able to compile and reproduce your problem, though.

Comment: btw you added some more snippets, but it still doesnt add up to a [mcve]. The most important feature of a mcve is that we can copy your code to reproduce the same behaviour you observe

Comment: sorry for being picky, but `using namespace std;` is exactly the same number of characters to type as the 4 `std::` you save, so brevity isnt a good excuse :P

Comment: "brevity" was the wrong word to use - I just meant that so far it was working and I didn't want to mess it up by missing somewhere the ::std, since I was trying to edit as fast as possible.

Comment: `if (j == 0 && carry != '0')`: what are the motivations for these tests? Do you really think you need them both?

Comment: Just use [GMP](https://gmplib.org) and be done.

Comment: EJIP, the carry might be 0, so I wouldn't have to carry a number to the next digit, when I finish multiplying the current digit in the first number with the last (from right to left) digit in the second number?

Comment: So you never have to carry at other times? Does that happen when you do it by hand?

Comment: EJIP, well, at other times the carry is added since we're still in the lopp? It's just that once I'm finished with the last(first) digit in the second number, I exit the for-j-loop, so I need the if (j == 0 && carry != 0) to add the carry in case it is larger than 0.

Comment: A funny story about a bug I found recently in my own code: My hand-coded `intToStr()` returned in _certain_ cases strings with `*(/)*,-*` instead of the digits I expected (and got usually). The mistake was pretty simple: `bool minus = false; if (value < 0) { value = -value; minus = true; }` which failed in exactly one case: `INT_MIN`. Hence, the following separation of digits did the `% 10` on negative numbers which became negative as well and thus added to `'0'` provided exactly things like `*(/)*,-*`. I thought, it could be worth to tell you this... ;-) Happy debugging.

Comment: Scheff, wow, thank you - adding **abs** did get rid of the weird signs, but the middle digits continue to be off, and I have no idea what might have led to any negative numbers, considering that I'm only multiplying and adding positive ones, or caused different results between a * b and b * a. Still thank you!

Comment: Forget about large numbers with `9` in them, if you try simply doing `9*9` you get `0x1f 0x2b` [as a result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d3d5a1f60308542). Step through in a debugger to work out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::string` `char` is signed and it gets negative when you add `'0'` and use it later for the `carry` and `tmp[z]` so its better to store it in a temporary `ìnt`

```
6789*9876
---------
           int(char(res + '0'))
-------------------------------
0+9*6+0=54 102
0+9*7+5=68 116
0+9*8+6=78 126
0+9*9+7=88 -120
8+8*6+0=56 104
8+8*7+5=69 117
8+8*8+6=78 126
8+8*9+7=87 -121
9+7*6+0=51 99
8+7*7+5=62 110
7+7*8+6=69 117
8+7*9+6=77 125
2+6*6+0=38 86
9+6*7+3=54 102
7+6*8+5=60 108
7+6*9+6=67 115
```

So you can change your code like this:

```
    int res = ((tmp[z] - '0') + (num[i] - '0') * (rhs.num[j] - '0') + (carry - '0'));
    carry = (res / 10) + '0';
    tmp[z] = (res % 10) + '0';
    if (j == 0)
    {
        tmp[z - 1] = carry;
    }
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/0mAvwE)</kbd>